# In Javascript - what do multiple commas do in a var statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have been looking through new wordpress theme twentyfourteen and notice the following line in their javascript file:

```
var nav = $( '#primary-navigation' ), button, menu;
```

Can somebody explain me what does it mean, it does not look like a multiple variable assignment in a single line. Also `button` and `menu` are not defined yet, so how come it does not produce an error?

Comment: `var x, y, z` == `var x; var y; var z`.

Answer (score 5):

You are just declaring three variables and assigning value to only `nav`. Both `button` and `menu` will have `undefined`, by default.

```
var a = 1, b, c;
console.log(a, b, c);
```

**Output**

```
1 undefined undefined
```

Instead, if you see something like this

```
var d = (1, 2, 3);
console.log(d);
```

**Output**

```
3
```

The expressions within the brackets will be evaluated from left to right and the result of the last evaluation will be assigned to `d`.

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to the following:

```
var nav = $( '#primary-navigation' );
var button;
var menu;
```

`button` and `menu` are undefined and are typically referenced in your example as variables that are used later throughout the script.

Answer (score 2):

That is the same as

```
var nav = $( '#primary-navigation' );
var button;
var menu;
```

And the reason for it is for avoiding variable hoisting.
More about variable hoisting:
http://thecomputersarewinning.com/post/a-dangerous-example-of-javascript-hoisting/